# Secure boot idea block usb boot

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I saw when my computer battery was low, it automaticly hibernate and when i opened it again i dont see boot device option or bios setting keys. So if we send hibernate code every shutdown or reboot, can we block usb boot hacks?

Comment: now, please answer.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit more, I couldn’t understand what you want to know??Whats usb boot hacks??

Comment: If you just want to stop booting from USB, you should be able to disable it in BIOS.

Comment: @EnesKuray - In case you want to stop booting from USB, by disable it in BIOS-settings, then you need to enable BIOS-password for each login and this BIOS-password is not as secure as the one of Linux-login-display-manager ... you also could write a script to chmod 0000 /dev/usb - or to comment the usb-recognition in /etc/fstab with #.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to prevent someone from accessing your HDD by booting up a system from USB? If an attacker have physical access to your machine, he can always take out your HDD and do what he want. So in this case it won't help if you could disable booting from USB. This "hibernating method" is no more safer then password protecting your BIOS.

Drive encryption is the only way to prevent an attacker with physical access to your machine from accessing your files.

I see you want an answer from credible/official source, so for example look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818200). It also says that the resolution is to encrypt your files/drive.

Answer (score 0):

A simple attack vector on the protection scheme you proposed is to let the computer wake up from hibernation and then forcefully restart it. Upon next boot it will boot normally, allowing access to the BIOS settings key and USB booting.

However, in order to give a more precise answer you'll need to provide additional details. The kind of functionality you're describing is probably implemented by your computer's UEFI firmware (and not BIOS which isn't sophisticated enough). So the answer might depend on the exact UEFI firmware you have (as different vendors might implement different protections there).

Comment: it do not support it.